# Basement Rough-in Identification

Tags: plumbing, basement, shower, toilet

Trying to identify what is what.  I originally thought the 3.5" by the wall was Toilet, but i don't think 5" away from "unfinished" wall is enough space. So the other 3.5" (2) must be the toilet?  What is the other 3.5"(1) then.  My guess on the others are (3) Shower and (4) vanity?

-Thanks for any advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you remove all that junk out of view before taking a picture?

Answer (score 1):

1 is a spare stack and it's 3" abs

2 is the toilet also 3"

3 is a vent and

4 is a sink.

It's a pretty bad rough in. If 3 is in fact a vent why is it so far away from the wall?
If it's for a shower/tub why is it so close to the wall?

**This is what your rough in should look like**[image]

3 must be a vent.

***EDIT***
**This is an example of what is going on**
[image]www.doityouself.com

If you can pour water down one of the 2-inch pipes and see that it holds water at level, that would indicate it has a trap as in the pipe at the far left of the image. Traps it only ever be installed at floor drains or shower drains it sink drain will not have a trap under the floor.

Your 3-inch that's close to the wall may be repurposed as a shower drain provided it's vented.

In your image pipe number 3 could very well be intended as a shower drain, just in a very poor location.

Comment: I agree, and I assume that #3 would fall in the same wall as #4, making its position with respect to the exterior wall irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Can the 3" by the wall (1) be used for a shower?  Assuming 3 is Vent, 2 is Toilet, and 4 is Sink?

Comment: It's really hard to say for sure without scoping the pipes or at least physically standing there and looking around down in the pipes. Sometimes rough ins are done by apprentices and it's hard to figure out exactly what they had intended. I'm going to add a photo to my answer that should give you an idea of what the requirements for everything are.

Comment: Fantastic description.  I will look into that tonight and report back. :)  I would have the other day, but the caps were glued on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Follow up:

1. Ended up reworking the entire plumbing as it just wouldn't work as-is.
2. 1 was 3" drain repurposed to 2" Sink with AAV.
3. 2 was 3" toilet, moved to better location
4. 3 was shower (w/trap), moved to better location.
5. 4 Vent or sink, moved to better locadtion (Sink with another AAV)

-Thanks to all who helped me on this.

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2 are toilet drains.   Might have been planned two bathrooms.

The only location that doesn't make sense is #3.  I am sure this is for a tub/show but makes no sense where they configured it.

So #4 is your sink drain.  That is set to go in the wall.  If your draw your wall perpendicular to the back wall then you will see that #2 is in a pretty good location for a toilet - well planned.   However #3 seems to be lined up in the wall too.

Showers/tubs can't exit through the wall unless it is raised.   But at the same time shower pans and tubs aren't standard.   So basically with any rough-in that wasn't pre-made for something specific you will move this.

For the shower you will simply need to break up the floor cut pipe where your shower/tub lines up, redo plumbing, and throw a bag or two of quickcrete down.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for the incite.  Yeah, this layout did not make logical sense to me.  Especially with the 2, 3' so close, and why in a 1000 ft2 basement would you need 2 toilets.

Comment: 3 is confusing to me as well, perhaps it is the vent as stated above, but then where is the shower?

Comment: 3 is your shower for sure.   The only thing in question is 1.   For some reason showers/tubs are almost always poured near outside walls.   That is just your normal basement bathroom layout.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time on this but wanted to share the results of this.

1. I ended up breaking the concrete and moving a few of the pipes so i was able to figure out what was what.
2. (2) in the picture was the only one with the Trap (Shower)
3. The other 3 (the 1 1/2" and the 2, 3") were tied into the main line.
4. I ended up using the #4 as the toilet, relocated 2 a bit for the shower drain, removed 3 and used #1 as the vanity sink.  I also added another sink near the toilet for a bar.

Note:  there was no VENT in the basement, in fact most of the house used AAV's for this purpose.  (So that's how i vented, no need to bring through the roof).

-thanks for everyone who helped.